# How to get the second of two div class instances using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

If I use the following code:

```
<style>
.a:nth-child(2){
    color: blue
}
</style>

<div class="a">Hello</div>
<div class="b">Goodbye</div>
<div class="a">Hello 2</div>
```

The text of the second div with the classname of 'a' is not changed to the color blue.

However, if I rearrange the divs

```
<style>
.a:nth-child(2){
    color: blue
}
</style>

<div class="a">Hello</div>
<div class="a">Hello 2</div>
<div class="b">Goodbye</div>
```

This works. How would I get the second div by classname as written in the first example using pure CSS?

Also, the :nth-of-type(n) syntax works exactly the same.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating this:

http://jsfiddle.net/mrmayfield/r61pztpb/

Comment: Not possible :/ You'll have to use javascript

Comment: Alright, it is confirmed as impossible. Thanks guys.

Comment: Do you know if it is always the last one? http://jsfiddle.net/r61pztpb/2/

Comment: It's exceedingly unlikely but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
.a:nth-of-type(3){
    color: blue
}
```

Or:

```
.a:nth-child(3){
    color: blue
}
```

Since `nth-of-type` goes by the type of element it is (`div` in this case) and `nth-child` goes by the child number within its parent container.

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r61pztpb/1/)

Comment: But if I have content dynamically loading, and I don't know how many divs are in between my first 'a' div and my second 'a' div, how can I structure this in CSS? I would have thought for sure CSS had a function similar to jQuery's .eq() function, but it seems not--I have read the answers of the similar question listed above, but it is still not clear to me whether this functionality is present in CSS3.

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to use javascript at that point.

Comment: The good news is that there will be something like this in [CSS4](http://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/structural-pseudo-class/)  :-).

Comment: @kaz the bad news is that there won't be a CSS4 :P .. CSS3 introduced a modular CSS where each module can have different revisions. Eventually —and hopefully— one day the 3 will drop and it will continue to exist as CSS :D

Comment: Well I will eagerly await this feature then! jQuery has a fine API for this kind of work but I'd much prefer to keep my concerns separated.

Comment: @Camou: It's neither good news or bad news, just a misinterpretation of the news. There will be a Selectors 4, but nobody knows when browsers will implement the most popular features.